Why is the Vice President following Mary and what does she Want?
Okay, so in season 2, the vice president starts to follow Mary around. It felt creepy and it was like she wanted something from Mary badly. So, what did Ririka Momobami (the Vice President and twin sister to the President) want from Mary so badly that she would practically be Mary's stalker/shadow? Does Ririka like her or does Ririka need something?
